# Access SQLite Data and Display it in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

as new to C# and SQLite world, how can i possibly display data from SQLite in the DataGridView in C#?
I really don't have any idea on how to do it. Even I tried some tutorials from the internet but I don't get it right. And most of them are using MySQL.

Comment: Well, if you show your efforts, you will find someone to help you to fix the errors, without code your question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) ADO.NET provider for connecting to your sqlite db.

When the references are added, you can write queries, like

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=test.db3"))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM random_table_name";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"));
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

1. Put the read values into a List or some kind of collection.
2. After finishing, you can bind your Data Grid View into your list. [It's a good msdn page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)